# Is there any way to convert a CVSNT repo to SVN without using cvs2svn?

Tags: svn, repository, cvs, cvsnt

My end goal is to convert a **CVSNT** repository with its entire history, branches, tags, etc. to an **SVN** repository.

I can't seem to get **cvs2svn** to successfully convert from CVSNT to SVN. Even after looking through multiple forums and trying their suggestions.

So, I am looking for a way to convert a CVSNT repository to a CVS repository or other type of repository that can then be successfully converted to an SVN repository.

Comment: I would not think so, no. For example, the cvs2git tools use cvs2svn as a starting point. You are probably better off trying to get help on StackOverflow with your cvs2svn error messages (and show what you've done to debug them).

Comment: I'm not getting any error messages. The base CVS files under CVSROOT (checkoutlist, modules, etc.) get copied but none of the files that I checked into my repository are copied over.